# "User does not have an AdSense account" message when using a service account to access the AdSense Management API

Tags: oauth-2.0, admob, adsense, adsense-api

I really looked it up and found no suitable answer.

I have both an AdSense and AdMob accounts sharing the same publisher ID. They're active and when I try the API in https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/list it works fine.

1) Created an AdSense Account with my personal email.
2) Enabled the AdSense Management API in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
3) Created a Service Account and downloaded the credential's secrets json file
5) Waited at least 48 hours. Probably more, now.
4) My pom.xml file has these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-adsense</artifactId>
    <version>v1.4-rev160-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

5) My code

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream( "/data/admob-test.json" );
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream( is ).createScoped( AdSenseScopes.all() );
    credential.refreshToken();
    return credential;
}

private static AdSense initializeAdsense() throws Exception {

    // Authorization.
    Credential credential = authorize();

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // Set up AdSense Management API client.
    AdSense adsense = new AdSense.Builder( httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential ).setApplicationName( "random-app-name" ).build();

    return adsense;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    try {
        AdSense adsense = initializeAdsense();

        // I get an exception on the following line:
        Accounts accounts = adsense.accounts().list().execute(); 

        if ( ( accounts.getItems() != null ) && !accounts.getItems().isEmpty() ) {

            System.out.println( "SUCCESS!" );
        }
        else {

            System.out.println( "FAIL!" );
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

6) Error message

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "User does not have an AdSense account.",
    "reason" : "noAdSenseAccount"
  } ],
  "message" : "User does not have an AdSense account."
}
```

Am I missing something? I've followed every stackoverflow entry I've found about this subject to no avail.

When I debug, the credential object looks ok, with all the service account secrets loaded. It gets an AuthToken when I do the credential.refreshToken(); command. I don't understand what's missing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, have you fixed this as yet? Getting the same problem.

Comment: Have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

from https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started
"Service Accounts are not supported ..."

If you follow the getting stared guide/ examples and turn on offline access you can generate (and store) a re-usable token that can be used to make future calls.

If you are using the java example at https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/blob/master/java/v1.x/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/adsense/cmdline/AdSenseSample.java take a look in DATA_STORE_DIR

Comment: Can you give more details? What do you mean by " turn on offline access" and what is supposed to be at DATA_STORE_DIR?